# Fatal Runtime Error During dashDB Container Deployment

Tags: docker, dashdb

I am trying to deploy dashDB and am following instructions at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/admin/linux_deploy.html.

Environment:  RHEL 7.3

Docker Version:

```
Client:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-58.git87f2fab.el7.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.9.2
 Git commit:      87f2fab/1.13.1
 Built:           Mon Mar 19 18:55:01 2018
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-58.git87f2fab.el7.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.9.2
 Git commit:      87f2fab/1.13.1
 Built:           Mon Mar 19 18:55:01 2018
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
 Experimental:    false
```

1. downloaded db2wh_v2.9.0_devc.tar.gz
2. ran the following command successfully

   docker load -i db2wh_v2.9.0_devc.tar.gz
3. ran the following command

   docker run -d -it --privileged=true --net=host --name=Db2wh -v /mnt/clusterfs:/mnt/bludata0 -v /mnt/clusterfs:/mnt/blumeta0 store/ibmcorp/db2wh_ce:v2.9.0-db2wh_devc-linux

At the end of command execution, the container is running:

```
ebed4f4b5d5f        store/ibmcorp/db2wh_ce:v2.9.0-db2wh_devc-linux               "/usr/sbin/init"         50 minutes ago      Up 50 minutes
```

But the container log shows errors that prevent a complete deployment:

```
219 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN)

 virtualization docker.

 architecture x86-64.



to [0;31mDb2 Warehouse[0m!



name to <dpywdcwash01.sl.bluecloud.ibm.com>.

zing machine ID from random generator.

dd dependency job for unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer, ignoring: Unit is masked.

OK  [0m] Reached target Local File Systems.

OK  [0m] Reached target Timers.

OK  [0m] Reached target Swap.

OK  [0m] Reached target Paths.

OK  [0m] Created slice Root Slice.

OK  [0m] Listening on Delayed Shutdown Socket.

OK  [0m] Created slice System Slice.

OK  [0m] Created slice system-selinux\x2dpol...grate\x2dlocal\x2dchanges.slice.

OK  [0m] Listening on Journal Socket.

 Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...

 Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...

OK  [0m] Reached target Slices.

OK  [0m] Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.

 Starting Journal Service...

OK  [0m] Started Create Volatile Files and Directories.

 INFO [0m] Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown is not active.

DEPEND[0m] Dependency failed for Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.

emd-update-utmp-runlevel.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.

OK  [0m] Started Journal Service.

OK  [0m] Reached target System Initialization.

OK  [0m] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.

OK  [0m] Reached target Sockets.

OK  [0m] Reached target Basic System.

 Starting LSB: Bring up/down networking...

 Starting System Logging Service...

 Starting System Security Services Daemon...

 Starting SASL authentication daemon....

OK  [0m] Started System Logging Service.

OK  [0m] Started SASL authentication daemon..

OK  [0m] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.

 Starting D-Bus System Message Bus...

OK  [0m] Started LSB: Bring up/down networking.

OK  [0m] Reached target Network.

OK  [0m] Reached target Network is Online.

 Starting LSB: Supports the direct execution of binary formats....

OK  [0m] Started LSB: Supports the direct execution of binary formats..

OK  [0m] Started System Security Services Daemon.

OK  [0m] Reached target Multi-User System.

 Starting SystemD Unit file to manage nping echo-server as a service...

OK  [0m] Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.

OK  [0m] Started SystemD Unit file to manage nping echo-server as a service.

OK  [0m] Started The entrypoint script for initializing the service.

4.549628] start_dashDB_local.sh[192]: /usr/lib/dashDB_local_common_functions.sh: line 2293: /tmp/etc_profile-LOCAL.cfg: No such file or directory

5.032963] start_dashDB_local.sh[192]: mkdir: missing operand

5.033766] start_dashDB_local.sh[192]: Try 'mkdir --help' for more information.

5.190899] start_dashDB_local.sh[192]: The IBM Db2 Warehouse container's environment is not set up yet.

5.208240] start_dashDB_local.sh[192]: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

5.214890] start_dashDB_local.sh[192]: FATAL RUNTIME ERROR DETECTED

5.221328] start_dashDB_local.sh[192]: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

5.227972] start_dashDB_local.sh[192]: Dumping system configuration details to help diagnose the problem

5.358169] start_dashDB_local.sh[192]: The IBM Db2 Warehouse container's environment is not set up yet.

5.375395] start_dashDB_local.sh[192]: Generation of diagnostic information complete; stopping deployment of container immediately
```

Confirmed that the /tmp/etc_profile-LOCAL.cfg file is not present in the container.  This seems similar to related issues that have been corrected by upgrading Docker but I believe I am running a recent enough version.

Answer (score 0):

You need Docker Enterprise Edition (EE) or Community Edition (CE). I think what you have there is the older/original docker.

You need to be on V17.06 or above  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/admin/local_prereqs-Linux.html#local_prereqs-Linux

```
> docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:06:25 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:06:25 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Uninstall `docker` and install `docer-ce` (or `docker-ee`) as per https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/fedora/

Comment: This makes good sense, thanks.  Will the install instructions provided above work on RHEL?  The RHEL install instructions https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ee/rhel/ say to delete all existing docker repos - will I lose all images we have built?  If so, is there a convenient way to export/save for later import/load into the new installation?

Comment: The containers would be lost, but that should be no different than when you upgrade Db2 Warehouse, with docker you install a new version you rename (or delete) the old container and spin up a new one. The mount points `-v /mnt/clusterfs:/mnt/bludata0 -v /mnt/clusterfs:/mnt/blumeta0` hold the actual database data, and survive.  Well that is the theory as far as I understand it.  If you wish, you can take a snapshot backup of cluster filesystem  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/admin/backup_restore.html

Comment: I think you would want to follow the re-deploy process https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/admin/redeploying.html

Comment: Thanks!  I will install as recommended and report back.